# How to break up a screen/window's QPainter to paint only a portion?

Tags: c++, qt, qpainter

I am coding a game - I have a Board class that is composed of a table/grid of "Spaces" - both Spaces and the Board have a virtual method 'render' being passed a QPainter reference.  I want to (if possible) use the painter for the main board and to pass to each Space JUST the rectangle of the space on the screen that it should paint.  Is that possible?

Like if the board occupies a rectangle 0,0 -> 2000,2000 and the rectangle passed to the top left space would be 0,0->100,100 - the rectangle for the next space over would be 100,0->200,100 - but as far as it would see, its rectangle would just be 0,0->100,100 no matter what - so I could break up the work being done.  Here's a simple example:

```
class Space
{
     // ...
public:
     //...
     virtual void render(QPainter *painter);
};

class Board
{
     QList<QList<Space>> mLstBoard;
public:
     // ...
     virtual void render(QPainter *painter);
};

class GamePanel : public QWidget
{
     Q_OBJECT
     Board *mBoard;
public:
     // ...
};

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
     Q_OBJECT

     GamePanel mPnlMain;
public:
     //...
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     QApplication a(argc, argv);
     MainWindow wnd;
     wnd.show();
     return(a.exec());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [QPainter::translate()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpainter.html#translate-2) on the QPainter object you pass to the Space objects, in order to adjust the location of the origin-point that they "see" when they draw with it.

If you want to mask what they draw to make sure they only draw within their allotted region, you can do that by calling [QPainter::setClipRect()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpainter.html#setClipRect) on the QPainter before calling their render() method.

Of course, once you have done that, you might want to just go the whole way and make each Space into its own separate [QWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html), and lay them out as child widgets using a [QGridLayout](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qgridlayout.html), since that seems to be the direction you're headed anyway.

Comment: Why not QGraphicsScene? Qt already implemented all those low-level space divisions, trying to emulate that on higher lever of abstraction will end in tears

Comment: QGraphicsScene is also a good choice.  The grid-of-adjacent-squares pattern is simple enough that it can be done a number of ways.

Comment: I'm trying to limit how much I use "controls" as I need to quickly render (60 fps) the game so I am trying to put the painting into the parts - but breaking it up so I'm not handling the entire board in one shot.  I somewhat did that when I did a PacMan Clone - but with that I had the board as a single JPG and then over top of that, I painted the ghosts, pacman, food, fruit, and powerups special.  The only widget components I have are the MainWindow, main panel, and About Dialog - Everything else is a model object that either handles the data model or paint/render itself.

Comment: I'll look into QGraphicsScene - I've never heard of it but I'm interested in possibly learning how it can help me render the whole board on a regular iterative basis

Comment: @SethD.Fulmer `QGraphicsScene` or widgets inteded to interface with OpenGL or OSG are more preferable for a game use-case. `QPainter` is a high-level graphics API which passes at least two levels of abstraction to reach OS-level rendering engine, and most of its implementation is hidded, but it is designed to draw _widgets_ in a consistent way where some properties are passed from global settings.